# XBAP runtime error

Tags: wpf, xbap

Afternoon SOF,

I have an XBAP sat on a company server which runs on 99/100 terminals.
The odd one out will crash at the install page, reading:

> > Faulting application presentationhost.exe, version 4.0.40305.0, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, fault address 0x00012afb.

I am sure it has something to do with the installed .NET frameworks on the 'odd' system,
but can find no real difference between the two sets of installs.

Can anybody give me a hand, or perhaps a quick list of recomended re-installs *?

(* .Net Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4, and 4 Ext - i am guessing)

Answer (score 0):

XBAPs tend to be quite problematic, some possible problems and solutions can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/20fec550-bc3e-4001-94b2-debf46c4533f), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/a1b5de5a-f2f9-4d3e-8af1-37d191c1fd6a), [and here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e15f2a25-1511-42cd-91f0-350678cfb87e). My best guess for the root of your problem is that terminal having a different version of .NET installed. The second link above also contains a short reinstall process.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Kind of - I switched out the old .Net installs for new installs, but it had no effect on IE... FireFox has, however, proven itself.

Comment: Then it's a most likely a problem with your IE. The XBAP doesn't _actually_ run in your browser, it runs in as an out-of-process .exe called PresentationHost.exe. I would suggest checking your version of IE. XBAPs only started being supported by .NET 3.0 (released Nov '06) so versions of IE before 8 probably won't support your app.